# Chromium: prevent unpacking tar.gz

Tags: google-chrome, tar, chromium, gzip, mime-types

The latest Chrome and Chromium seems to unpack .tar.gz files automatically for me on OS X and Linux. When using `wget` with the same URL, it shows:

```
$ wget http://mydomain/dir/file.tar.gz
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: ... [application/octet-stream]
...
```

Verifying the file type:

```
$ file file.tar.gz
file.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)
```

When doing the same for the file downloaded with Chrome or Chromium:

```
$ file file.tar.gz
file.tar.gz: POSIX tar archive
```

Note, that Chrome/Chromium obviously kept the file name, but expanded it (the file size is ~4 times bigger than from the wget-downloaded file).

As website administrator how can I prevent Chrome/Chromium from unpacking the file?

**Update:**

According to `curl -I http://mydomain/dir/file.tar.gz` our Apache/Tomcat combo responds with

```
Content-Encoding: x-gzip
```

Tried `.tar.gz` files from other websites are not unpacked by chrome and don't report the `Content-Encoding: x-gzip` header, so there seems to be a relation.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to our hosting provider the header `Content-Encoding: x-gzip` was caused by the Apache in front of our Tomcat. Removing following line:

```
LoadModule deflate_module               modules/mod_deflate.so
```

from its configuration solved the problem.

Comment: Disabling [`mod_deflate`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_deflate.html) will disable HTTP compression for *all* files, which is probably not what you want; HTTP compression is important. A better option is to configure Apache to not alter `.gz` files, with something like [`RemoveOutputFilter`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#removeoutputfilter).

Comment: @MultiplyByZer0 Maybe you want to write a standalone answer to be accepted?

Answer (score 10):

Your web server is likely sending the `.tar.gz` file with a `content-encoding: gzip` header, causing the web browser to assume a gzip layer was applied only to save bandwidth, and what you really intended to send was the `.tar` archive. Chrome un-gzips it on the other side like it would with any other file (`.html`, `.js`, `.css`, etc.) that it receives gzipped (it dutifully doesn't modify the filename though).

To fix this, make sure your web server serves `.tar.gz` files without the `content-encoding: gzip` header.

More Info: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83292

Comment: I already have changed the Tomcat to send `application/octet-stream` for `gz` files (see the `wget` output). It did not change anything. Beside that, it seems to be a new feature of Chrome - can't remember it already had unpacked files 3 months ago.

Comment: @ThomasS. As far as I know, your issue is due to sending the `content-encoding: gzip` header, it doesn't have to do with the `application/octet-stream` content type. In other words, I am advising you to change your `content-encoding` header, not your `Content-Type` header.

Comment: The bug is marked fixed, but I just found the same issue in 2018 but with `.tgz` extension.  Example URL: https://www.lysator.liu.se/~jc/wotsap/download/wotsap-0.7.tgz