# Prevent Chrome to unzip files while downloading

Tags: google-chrome, zip

My Chrome keeps unzipping gz files while downloading. I don't know how to prevent this except turning on IExplorer or other browsers. I can't find any settings or any flag to prevent this.

**What happens**:
I download a file, e.g., http://example.com/file.mysql.gz
The file.mysql.gz is downloaded but it is uncompressed, so even if it keeps the name file.mysql.gz, it is a huge plain text mysql dump file.

Those are the version of Chrome I am using:

- Google Chrome on Windows 8: Version 45.0.2454.101 m
- Chromium on Ubuntu 14.04: Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

But this happens since many months now, so I think many versions have been changed since the first time I experienced this.

Note that [Chromium: prevent unpacking tar.gz](https://superuser.com/questions/940605/chromium-prevent-unpacking-tar-gz) doesn't apply, it is not a server problem, I don't have the same problem with any other browsers.

Comment: I use the exact same version of Chrome on Windows for you and I do not experience this. Seems like third party software might be causing it, possibly an extension that syncs between all versions of Chrome? Try using incognito or disabling all extensions.

Comment: @Insane Thank you for your answer. I tried as you suggested disabling all the extensions (mainly Google Drive related) and downloading the gz in incognito. Two different users, two different S.O. Nothing to do.
Something more strange, if the file gz contains only a plain text is downloaded uncompressed, if it contains other files it remains compressed. The file is indeed compressed anyway since other browsers download it compressed.

Comment: You need to continue to look at your configuration.  I can download archived mysql compressed files all daylong with Chrome and they are not extracted unless I manually do it.

Comment: October 2016, I still have this problem for all my chromes,in Ubuntu and Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found: It is an actual bug of Chrome:

See:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47951

and:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=268085

Seems this issue didn't get too much credits, and still there is not final solution. I solved in two ways: with an automatic script that compress my mysql file automatically, or using another browser when I can't wait 10 minutes to download a huge uncompresssed dump.

Comment: The linked issues describe the opposite effect: Chrome compresses the files.